# Ubuntu не запускается после установки

Tags: ubuntu

Убунту не запускается после установки. При запуске с флешки она проработает немного и потом просто зависает, а после установки и вовсе не запускается графическая оболочка, помогает ввод параметра nomodeset, но тогда разрешение экрана маленькое и мыльное, как сделать её адекватной?
Ноут: hp pavilion 15

Comment: Какой графический драйвер используется?

Comment: А если `vga=normal`?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)

Comment: Запускается через nomodeset теперь проблема драйвер на nvidia geforce 1050 M поставить.
Вывод после попытки установить драйвер: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: nvidia-dkms-390 (= 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Почему у вас сломаны пакеты - это отдельный вопрос. На этом сайте не принято задавать несколько вопросов в одной теме. В общем, вам нужно прежде всего удалить все установленные графические драйверы, затем перезагрузиться и установить nvidia.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf я перезагрузить я не могу адекватно без nomodeset. Пробовал уже по разному

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была с несовместимостью драйверов для видеокарты Nvidia (GTX 1050 в моем случае)
После выхода версии Ubuntu 19.10 все нормализовалось.